# How can I make this delete button work?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

How can I make this delete button work?
Public Class Form1
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

```
Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
    dbSource = "Data Source = C:Desktop\AddressBook\AddressBook.mdb"

    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    con.Open() 

    sql = "SELECT * From Master_Details"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "Master_Details")

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows.Count
    inc = -1

    MsgBox("Database is now open")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Database is now closed")

    txtcode.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(0)
    txtdprt.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(1)
    txtgroup.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(2)
    txtepf.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(3)
    txtdesignation.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(4)
    txtename.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(5)
    txtjdate.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(6)
    txtdob.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(7)
    txtnicn.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(8)
    txtgender.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(9)
    txttcodes.Text = ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(0).Item(10)
    Return
End Sub

Private Sub btndelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No 
        MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows.Count).Delete()
    MaxRows = MaxRows - 1
    inc = 0
    da.Update(ds, "Master_Details")
    NavigateRecords()
End Sub
```

Comment: work means, how to run this program without errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly specifying which row to delete -- it's always row `ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows.Count`, which is one past the last row.

Comment: i want to delete all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Use case statement... Put all of this in your delete button click event...

```
  Select Case MsgBox("Do you really want to delete this record?", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "CONFIRM DELETE")
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            'NOT SURE IF THIS IS RIGHT, BUT THE SELECT IS IN WHICH YOU WANT...'
            Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
            ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows(ds.Tables("Master_Details").Rows.Count - 1).Delete()
            MaxRows = MaxRows - 1
            inc = 0
            da.Update(ds, "Master_Details")
            NavigateRecords()
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
             MsgBox ("Operation Cancelled")
           Exit Sub
    End Select
```

Also set a break point on your first line if the messagebox result is yes and step through your code, this will show what is going on...

Thanks!

Comment: it says there is no row at position 2 :(

Comment: Where it says rows.count try adding -1 to the end of it... I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot Sir ! but now it says syntax error for this part = da.Update(ds, "Master_Details")

Comment: this is the error .

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((Code = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND Department IS NULL) OR (Department = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Group IS NULL) OR (Group = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND EPF IS NULL) OR (EPF = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Designation IS NULL) OR (Designation = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Employee name IS NULL'.

Comment: Set a breakpoint there and see what you have when you get there. If you don't have anything then you need to step back. Make sure you ds(data set) has what you want.